# Way to apply a :not against a group of element css selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selector

Given a group of inputs:

```
<div id="group">
    <input id="uno"   class="red"></input><br/>
    <input id="dos"   class="red"></input><br/>
    <input id="tres"  class="blue"></input><br/>
    <textarea id="a1" class="blue"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea id="a2" class="red"></textarea><br/>
</div>
```

I want to only select **non-blue class** input and textarea elements.  This successfully excludes blue textareas only, but the inputs are still selected:

```
$('#group').on('keypress', 'input,textarea:not(.blue)', function(e){
    $(e.target).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```

I would want to do something like `'(input,textarea):not(.blue)'` but that doesn't work.  Is there a way to apply a `:not` against a group of element selectors?

Here's a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/spencerw/wzvqjtna/

Comment: I apologize that I didn't mentioned that I knew about `'input:not(.blue),textarea:not(.blue)'` and didn't specify that I wanted to pass in a parameter to the function that hosted the `.on('keypress')` with a single `exclude` selector parameter that could be used in a single location (since I may use more than just `input` and `textarea` elements).  So, while @Arun P Johny and @taxicala's answers were both good, I'm choosing @gerald89's answer because it has the ability to apply the single `exclude` to the group.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

When you use multiple selectors each selector in it should be complete

```
$('#group').on('keypress', 'input:not(.blue),textarea:not(.blue)', function(e){
    $(e.target).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```

```js
$('#group').on('keypress', 'input:not(.blue),textarea:not(.blue)', function(e) {
  $(e.target).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">
  <input id="uno"   class="red"/><br/>
  <input id="dos"   class="red"/><br/>
  <input id="tres"  class="blue"/><br/>
  <textarea id="a1" class="blue"></textarea><br/>
  <textarea id="a2" class="red"></textarea><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that adding `:not` to a group would be possible the way you want to do, one correct way and solution would be doing as follows:

```
$('#group').on('keypress', 'input:not(.blue),textarea:not(.blue)', function(e){
    $(e.target).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can do like this

```
$('#group input,textarea').not(".blue").on('keypress', function(e){
    $(e.target).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```